# How to get admin option (i.e., value) of an attribute?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I would like to get the admin option (i.e., value) of an attribute in Magento 1.9. So far I have been able to do that:

```
<?php
define(CURRENT_STORE_ID, Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
// Display admin value of "attribute"
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(CURRENT_STORE_ID);
// Still display admin value of "attribute"
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
?>
```

The problem is, I cannot figure out how to switch back to the "normal" store after I retrieve the admin option (i.e., value) I needed.

**Edit:**

```
<?php
// Display the normal value of "attribute"
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
define(CURRENT_STORE_ID, Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
// Still display the normal value "attribute"
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(CURRENT_STORE_ID);
// Still display the normal value "attribute"
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using app emulations?

```
// Switch to Admin Store
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$adminEnvironmentEmulation = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($adminEnvironmentEmulation);

// Switch back to previous store
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
```

Comment: I had not. I just tried using app emulations and I am still getting admin values for both `echo`. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Comment: If you `echo` the value of the attribute first of all, before switching to admin store... do you get a different value?

Comment: If I `echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');` before anything switching store or app emulation then I am only getting the normal value for every `echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');`. Weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAdminLabel(string $attributeCode, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute $attribute */
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
    $optionLabel = $attribute
        ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
        ->getSource()->getOptionText($product->getData($attributeCode));

    return $optionLabel;
}
```